# DataGridViewTextBoxCell in edit mode steals keystrokes from Form even when using Form.KeyPreview

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, keyboard-events

I have:

```
this.KeyPreview = true;
```

set in my Form, which allows me to typically receive KeyDown events even if a child element has focus. However, I have a DataGridView containing DataGridViewTextBoxCell's and when I click them, I enter "edit mode" for the cell and this somehow has such exclusive access to the keyboard that I can no longer receive these key presses. As long as anything in my entire Form has focus I want my keyboard functionality to actually work.

Does anyone know a way of getting these KeyDown events anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Try handling the `KeyUp` event instead of `KeyDown`